# Include cell value in SUM only if the cell under it is number

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a following table:

```
z a 3 4 4 ...
1 x 1 a 9 ...
```

I would like to make a formula which will sum up cells in the first row, but will include cell in the sum only if the value of the cell itself is a number and the value of the cell in the same column in the second row is also number. For the example table, the result would be 7. The best I could do was

```
=SUM(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A1:J1);ISNUMBER(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(A1:J1)+1;COLUMN(A1:J1)))));A1:J1;0))
```

entered as array formula, but that didn't work (always returns 0). What formula could I use to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(A1:J1)*ISNUMBER(A2:J2),A1:J1)
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Yeah, it works! I just had to change the comma into semicolon to make it work.